# How to select cells in QtableWidget from list of indexes

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qtablewidget

In a QtableWidget, I would like to store the selected cells while I query a database and return the previously selected cells back to being selected.  My refresh of items on the QtableWidget clears the selection.  The user can select non-contiguous ranges of cells.

I have no problem getting the selected cells before I refresh the data with QtableWidget.selectedIndexes().

I have tried looping through the list of indexes and using setCurrentIndex but that only leaves me with the last index.  I have run out of ideas.  How can I restore the selected ranges of cells based on the stored indexes?

[image: QtableWidget with non-contiguous cells selected]

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from room_chart import *
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

class Guest_form(QDialog):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QDialog.__init__(self)
        self.ui = Ui_rooms_chart()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)
        self.build_chart()
        self.ui.book.clicked.connect(self.book)

    def book(self):
        self.indexes = self.ui.room_chart.selectedIndexes()
        #Do stuff
        self.build_chart()

        #This has the right behaviour but only selects the last index
        for x in range(len(self.indexes)):
            self.ui.room_chart.setCurrentIndex(self.indexes[x])
        self.ui.room_chart.setFocus()

    def build_chart(self):
        self.ui.room_chart.setRowCount(0)
        self.ui.room_chart.setColumnCount(0) 
        col_labels = []
        for x in range(8):
            current_day = datetime.now() + timedelta(days=x)
            col_labels.append(current_day.strftime('%a') + '\n' + current_day.strftime('%d/%m/%y'))
            self.ui.room_chart.setColumnCount(len(col_labels))
            self.ui.room_chart.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(col_labels)

        row_labels = []
        for x in range(8):
            row_labels.append(str(x))
            self.ui.room_chart.setRowCount(len(row_labels))
            self.ui.room_chart.setVerticalHeaderLabels(row_labels)
        self.button = QPushButton(self.ui.room_chart)
        self.button.setText("Push me")
        self.ui.room_chart.setCellWidget(0 , 0, self.button)


if __name__=="__main__":
    app=QApplication(sys.argv)
    myapp = Guest_form()
    myapp.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use the [`select()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qitemselectionmodel.html#select) method of [`QItemSelectionModel`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qitemselectionmodel.html):

```
def book(self):
    persistenIndex = map(QPersistentModelIndex, self.ui.room_chart.selectedIndexes())

    #Do stuff
    self.build_chart()

    for pix in persistenIndex:
        ix = QModelIndex(pix)
        self.ui.room_chart.selectionModel().select(ix, QItemSelectionModel.Select)

    self.ui.room_chart.setFocus()
```

**Note:** *It converts the `QModelIndex` to `QPersistentModelIndex` to avoid problems since it is not known if `build_chart()` deletes, moves or performs any other action that changes the position of the items.*

Comment: Thanks! I had to do some googling to understand the map function but it is a well written and helpful answer.

Comment: Can you explain why map retains the values but if I merely .append(QPersistentModelIndex(QModelIndex)) to a list and try to use it later it does not retain its values?

Comment: Also, self.ui.room_chart.setFocus() does not seem to be working.

Comment: @Dkellygb `persistenIndex = map(QPersistentModelIndex, self.ui.room_chart.selectedIndexes())` is equivalent to `persistenIndex = [QPersistentModelIndex(ix) for ix in self.ui.room_chart.selectedIndexes()]`